# adding elements from string array into defaultlistmodel

Tags: java, arrays, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I'm trying to update the JList by deleting a contact and its not updating the JList like I wanted it to.

Originally, the JList would look like this.

```
Broadcast //Not allowed to delete this element
Andy
Bobby
Chris
Brad
```

Assuming that I have deleted Andy off the list using a button. It should show

```
Broadcast //Not allowed to delete this element
Bobby
Chris
Brad
```

Instead it shows this on the JList.

```
contact0
contact2
contact3
contact4
```

I don't know what went wrong and I looked in many sources. I want it to return the actual names, not the contact#. Code is below.

```
private JList<String> listContacts;
private DefaultListModel<String> model;
private String[] contactList;

model = new DefaultListModel<String>();                                                             
contactList = controller.getContacts();
for(String contact : contactList){
    model.addElement(contact);
}
listContacts = new JList<String>();                                                                  
listContacts.setModel(model);

class MyButtonListener5 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(listContacts.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
            controller.displayMsg("Can't delete broadcast.\n");
        }
        else if(listContacts.getSelectedIndex() > 0){
            controller.displayMsg("You tried to delete " + listContacts.getSelectedValue() +".\n");
            model.remove(listContacts.getSelectedIndex());
            listContacts.setModel(model);
        }
        else{
            controller.displayMsg("No contact to delete. Please select one.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This is for contactList to getContacts. This method is in the controller class. I hope this clarifies why I'm having trouble.

```
public String[] getContacts(){
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[5];
    String[] names = new String[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        contacts[i] = new Contact("contact" + i);
        names[i] = contacts[i].getName();
    }
    return names;
}
```

This is in my Contact Class.

```
private String name;
private String nickname;

public Contact(){
    name = "";
    nickname = "";
}
public Contact(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix this by overriding the toString() method in your Contact class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getName();
}
```

Then you can return your contacts without `.getName()` and just directly add them to the list. [I recommend you taking a look at this example.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable)

```
private JList listContacts;
private DefaultListModel model;
private Contact[] contactList;

model = new DefaultListModel();                                                             
contactList = controller.getContacts();
for(Contact contact : contactList){
    model.addElement(contact);
}
listContacts = new JList();                                                                  
listContacts.setModel(model);

class MyButtonListener5 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(listContacts.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
            controller.displayMsg("Can't delete broadcast.\n");
        }
        else if(listContacts.getSelectedIndex() > 0){
            controller.displayMsg("You tried to delete " + listContacts.getSelectedValue() +".\n");
            model.remove(listContacts.getSelectedIndex());
            listContacts.setModel(model);
        }
        else{
            controller.displayMsg("No contact to delete. Please select one.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And your getContacts() method:

```
public Contact[] getContacts(){
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[5];
    contacts[0] = "Broadcast";
    contacts[1] = "Andy";
    contacts[2] = "Bobby";
    contacts[3] = "Chris";
    contacts[4] = "Brad";

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: If I already did that, how do I modify the existing code I have in this post? Or do I not need to?

Comment: You need to change your getContact method to return type Contact and return the contacts array. Also you need to change your DefaultListModel i guess...
Can you post your Contact() class? It would be extremly helpful...

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer :D

Please update your answer and add your contact class...

Comment: I updated my answer according to yours, and it turns out that it doesn't access contacts class. I included it and I got a new error.
incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to Contact[]
    [javac]  contactList = controller.getContacts();

Comment: I guess you forgot the return type of your getContacts() method:
`public Contact[] getContacts()`

Comment: Btw.: where are you assigning the names? ´contacts[i] = new Contact("contact" + i);´ This should be changed to :

contacts[0] = "Andy";

contacts[1] = "Bobby"; and so on...

Comment: I updated my answer and changed the getContacts method

Comment: Well I updated it and got cannot find symbol for changing my getContacts, specifically Contacts. contactList = controller.getContacts(); in that one, it said Contacts[] cannot be converted to a string. Lastly, I got this for the for-each loop, for-each not applicable to expression type I will update the code tomorrow. Also to answer your question, the names are already assigned in another class, the server.java. I have a lot of files and my code is all over the place. I'm just hoping I can fix this small problem without changing anything else. Lastly, each "client" has its own set of contacts.